# How can I write logical Column expression with AND and OR in SparkR?

Tags: r, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, sparkr

I need to add column to SparkR (spark version 2.1.1) dataset based on some logical criteria on several other columns. But obvious solution (using && or ||) do not work, I get "*invalid 'x' type in 'x && y'*" error. For example, using built-in `mtcars` dataset:

```
> dcars = as.DataFrame(mtcars)
> dcars$cool_enough <- dcars$cyl >= 6 && dcars$hp >= 180
Error in dcars$cyl >= 6 && dcars$hp >= 180 : invalid 'x' type in 'x && y'
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why `&&`? Simple `&` works OK:

```
sparkR.version()
# "2.1.1"

dcars$cool_enough <- dcars$cyl >= 6 & dcars$hp >= 170 # changed 180 to 170 for demonstration purposes
head(dcars)
```

Result:

```
   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb cool_enough
1 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4       FALSE
2 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4       FALSE
3 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1       FALSE
4 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1       FALSE
5 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2        TRUE
6 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1       FALSE
```

Alternatively, this gives the same result:

```
dcars <- withColumn(dcars,"cool_enough", dcars$cyl >= 6 & dcars$hp >= 170)
```

Comment: I was sure that I tried & as well and it did not work.. But now it works, thank you (I am R newbie, don't really get the difference). Thank you very much for the answer!